Power Apps creating new record and updating existing record
I am trying to create code that will update and be re used to update the record in power apps. But now the problem I have it updates the last record created on the list instead of creating a new record. Below is my code:
  If(
    IsBlank(BrowseGallery1.Selected.ID),
    Patch(
        'MyList',
        Defaults('MyList'),
        EditForm1.Updates,
        EditForm1_3.Updates
    ),
    Patch(
        'MyList',
        LookUp('MyList', ID = BrowseGallery1.Selected.ID),
        EditForm1.Updates,
        EditForm1_3.Updates
    )
);
Refresh('MyList');
ResetForm(EditForm1);
ResetForm(EditForm1_3);
Notify(
    If(
        IsBlank(BrowseGallery1.Selected.ID),
        "Created Successfully",
        "Successfully"
    ),
    NotificationType.Information
);
Navigate(
    HomePage,
    ScreenTransition.Cover
);

